# Erro na criação de tabela (ORA-00904)

Tags: sql, oracle

Não sei se são meus óculos com problemas, mas não consigo enxergar onde estou errando. Se puderem me ajudar.

Li que o erro poderia estar acontecendo pelo modo como estou declarando minha `PRIMARY KEY`, mas tentei de três formas diferentes e não obtive resultado.

```sql
CREATE TABLE USUARIO_BI_TREINAMENTO_ATM(
                                        ID       NUMBER(22) NOT NULL,
                                        USER     VARCHAR2(2000) NOT NULL,
                                        PASSWORD VARCHAR2(2000) NOT NULL,
                                        TOKEN    VARCHAR2(400),
            CONSTRAINT USUARIO_BI_TREINAMENTO_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

O erro é retornado:

> Erro a partir da linha : 1 no comando -
>
> ORA-00904: : identificador inválido

Comment: Me parece que você está utilizando Oracle e não Microsoft SQL Server. Veja a lista de palavras reservadas em https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm ou consulte a view `V$RESERVED_WORDS`.

Comment: Sim, estou mesmo, obrigada por observar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não pode criar uma tabela com uma coluna chamada **USER**, pois assim o banco se confunde com um comando da linguagem, para poder criar a coluna utilize as aspas **"USER"**, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
CREATE TABLE USUARIO_BI_TREINAMENTO_ATM(
                                        ID       NUMBER(22) NOT NULL,
                                        "USER"     VARCHAR2(2000) NOT NULL,
                                        PASSWORD VARCHAR2(2000) NOT NULL,
                                        TOKEN    VARCHAR2(400),
            CONSTRAINT USUARIO_BI_TREINAMENTO_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Isso também acontece quando você tenta criar uma coluna SET (abreviação de Setembro), OUT (abreviação de Outubro) e outros casos, é só usar o "" aspas.

Comment: Acabei descobrindo que PASSWORD também é uma palavra reservada. :T Mas obrigada! acabei não me atentando a esse detalhe.

Comment: Já tive problema num Sistema com log de usuário com um user MAX ...